# Reshape Pandas DataFrame with Time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'unit':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                           2, 2, 2, 
                           3, 3, 3, 3], 
               'time':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
                       1, 2, 3,
                       1, 2, 3, 4],
              'signals': [23.2, 23.4, 23.3, 23.5, 23.4,
                         22.1, 22.3, 22.4, 
                         23.8, 23.9, 24.1, 24.0]})
```

| unit | time | signals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23.2 |
| 1 | 2 | 23.4 |
| 1 | 3 | 23.3 |
| 1 | 4 | 23.5 |
| 1 | 5 | 23.4 |
| 2 | 1 | 22.1 |
| 2 | 2 | 22.3 |
| 2 | 3 | 22.4 |
| 3 | 1 | 23.8 |
| 3 | 2 | 23.9 |
| 3 | 3 | 24.1 |
| 3 | 4 | 24.0 |

now, I want to reshape df with Time

| time | unit | signals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 23.2 |
| 1 | 2 | 22.1 |
| 1 | 3 | 23.8 |
| 2 | 1 | 23.4 |
| 2 | 2 | 22.3 |
| 2 | 3 | 23.9 |
| 3 | 1 | 23.3 |
| 3 | 2 | 22.4 |
| 3 | 3 | 24.1 |
| 4 | 1 | 23.5 |
| 4 | 3 | 24.0 |
| 5 | 1 | 23.4 |

I try to use *groupby* :

```
new_df = df.groupby('time')
new_df.apply(lambda x: print(x))
```

It seems work. but still have some problem:

1. I want to exchange these two columns(time and unit).
2. I need a new DataFrame, but *groupby* does not return a DataFrame

How can I get this DataFrame in the desired format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) withc chnage order of columns by list:

```
df = df.sort_values(['time', 'unit'], ignore_index=True)[['time','unit','signals']]
```